# Add column to dataframe indicating presence of row in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'account_id': [1, 2, 3], 'type': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
```

|  | account_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 2 | b |
| 2 | 3 | c |

```
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'account_id': [2, 3, 4], 'type': ['b', 'a', 'c']})
```

|  | account_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | b |
| 1 | 3 | a |
| 2 | 4 | c |

In know how to find the intersection between those two dataframes with

```
pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how='inner', on=['account_id', 'type'])
```

|  | account_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | b |

But now I want to add a column `in b` to `df_a` where the value for the row is `True` if the row is present in `df_b`

I tried

```
def in_b(row):
  return (df_b['account_id'] == row['account_id']) & (df_b['type'] == row['type'])

df_a['in b'] = df_a.apply(lambda row: in_b(row))
```

But that gives a

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-309eba5e6ab0> in <module>()
----> 1 df_a['in b'] = df_a.apply(lambda row: in_b(row))
      2 df_a

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    356                 except ValueError as err:
    357                     raise KeyError(key) from err
--> 358             raise KeyError(key)
    359         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    360 

KeyError: 'account_id'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: pass `indicator=True` to `merge`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On option would be to use the `indicator` kwarg of [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge), then convert the indicator values to boolean:

indicator : bool or str, default False

> If True, adds a column to the output DataFrame called “_merge” with information on the source of each row. The column can be given a different name by providing a string argument. The column will have a Categorical type with the value of “left_only” for observations whose merge key only appears in the left DataFrame, “right_only” for observations whose merge key only appears in the right DataFrame, and “both” if the observation’s merge key is found in both DataFrames.

```
df_a = df_a.merge(df_b, on=['account_id', 'type'], how='left', indicator='in b')
df_a['in b'] = df_a['in b'].eq('both')
```

`df_a`:

```
   account_id type   in b
0           1    a  False
1           2    b   True
2           3    c  False
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an auxillary column `i` with value `1` in `df_b`, merge it an check for the 1s.

```
df_a['in b'] = ~df_a.merge(df_b.assign(i=1), how='left')['i']==1

# Out[229]: 
#    account_id type   in b
# 0           1    a  False
# 1           2    b   True
# 2           3    c  False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.set_index` and `.isin`:

```
df_a['in b'] = df_a.set_index(['account_id', 'type']).index.isin(df_b.set_index(['account_id', 'type']).index)
```

Output:

```
   account_id  type   in b
0           1     a  False
1           2     b   True
2           3     c  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df_c = df_b.copy()
df_c['in b'] = True
df_f = pd.merge(left = df_a, right = df_c, how = 'left', on = ['account_id', 'type'])
df_f['in b'].fillna(False, inplace = True)
```